# Gulpfile.js to handle multiple files in multiple folders

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm working regularly on several WordPress projects where I work building both themes and plugins at the same time. I have a gulpfile.js in my theme folder that compiles .scss into .css files. I'm wondering if I could build some sort of "master" gulpfile, put it on the root folder, and then compile .scss files whenever we have them. The idea is that, if any folder contains a /scss folder, then Gulp will compile it's main .scss files and then generate a /css folder (same idea could be adapted for compiled js files, images, etc).

Here's my task that compiles .scss files so far.

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
        sass = require( 'gulp-sass' ),
        autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' ),
        minifycss = require( 'gulp-minify-css' ),
        rename = require( 'gulp-rename' ),
        clean = require( 'gulp-clean' ),
        concat = require( 'gulp-concat' ),
        cache = require( 'gulp-cache' ),
        notify = require( 'gulp-notify' ),
        projectTitle = 'Project Name';

// styles task
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/styles/*.scss' )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/styles/'], outputStyle: 'expanded' }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );

// styles task
gulp.task( 'editor-styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/styles/editor-styles.scss' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/styles/'] }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );

// watch task
gulp.task( 'watch', function() {

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch( 'src/styles/**/*.scss', [ 'styles' ] );

});
```

What is the best approach in this case to build a global gulpfile.js that works like this? Also it would be ideal if the task compiles only what is necessary (I've seen some tasks that compiles everything all the time).

Answer (score 0):

```
./sites/**/scss/*.scss
```

This works, put this inside your gulp.watch and gulp.src

let's say you have a workspace aka root.
You install gulp and gulp sass there. Create a folder there which will contain all your projects, i've called mine `sites`. So if you have 10 different sites, e.g. site1, site2, site3. It should all go inside `sites` folder.

It watches all sites/[random folder name]/scss folder for all `.scss` files and outputs the `css` inside of it. I don't know how to generate a `css` map and put output there though.